# fancyBox 2 Vimeo issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I'm trying the embed a Vimeo video on dreamweaver cs6. I have looked at similar issues and found one the same but the answer however did not solve my problem.

I have a plain html 5 file with all the necessary scripts and style sheets attached but i keep getting a spinning icon in firefox and in chrome i get an error within the fancybox frame work.

However it works fine in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M_F7/nZH9L/18/

This is the code im using in dreamweaver

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<a class="fancybox-media" href="https://vimeo.com/32240946"><img src="https://secure-b.vimeocdn.com/ts/217/963/217963030_295.jpg"></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    helpers: {
        media: {}
    }
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Check the paths to js and css files (or try setting absolute paths so you can see those files standalone in the browser) What is the error you get in Firefox btw?

Comment: Thanks JFK i will give that a go, in firefox i get the continuous spinning icon as if its loading but thats all.

Comment: @JFK I set absolute paths and dropped the s in href="https://vimeo.com/32240946" but still no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Try changing `https` by `http` ... wonder why jsfiddle is working fine. Can you share a link?

Comment: @JFK I have tried dropping the s so its just http but that hasn't work either this is the link to JSFiddle that does work http://jsfiddle.net/M_F7/nZH9L/18/ but as soon as i load the index file from dreamweaver it won't. unfortunately i cant link to that because it in my local files